# How to expand a class for more element in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, class, project

I'm new student of a class in React.

I just put down this code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            cnt: 0

        };
    }


    handleDecrement = () => {
        this.setState({
            cnt: this.state.cnt + 1
        });
    }

    handleIncrement = () => {
        this.setState({
            cnt: this.state.cnt - 1
        });
    }




    
    render() {
        return (

            <><div className = "btn">
                
                <div>
                    <img src= "images/cart.png" alt="cart" 
                </div>
                    <button onClick={this.handleDecrement}>+</button>
                    <p>{this.state.cnt} </p>
                    <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>-</button>
            </div>
```

the code is returning what I asked, its a simple button that increse and decrease a number, can you please help me out to add this class tu multiple buttons?

I would like to add 6 buttons.

thanks

Comment: What keeps you adding 4 more `<button>` tags? Are you going to add the _same_ button 6 times? Are you going to add the buttons from an array?

Comment: If I add for more buttons when I click alla buttons increase and decrease.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't wrap my head around what is your desired outcome here.

Comment: Basicly I would like to get 6 button that work by them selves, my outcome now is that if I click in 1 button all of them change.

Comment: Can you share the _not-working-code_ with the 6 buttons you have instead of this?

Comment: Where can I do that?

Comment: You can edit the question, since this is a working code, it is hard to help. With not-working code it would be easier to point out the mistakes